# Can't click link added to header of a block

Tags: 7, views, blocks, navigation

In Drupal 7 I created a views page, and I want users to have the option to view the results either as a list, or with thumbnails (like on a lot of websites). The only way I can think of doing that is creating one page with the results as a list, and having a link to another page with the results that have thumbnails.

But my question is, how do I add just a random link to the top of my block page that will direct users to the 'thumbnail' page?

I tried to use 'unfiltered text' in the header and put the html for a link in there, and when I went to the page it looked like a link, but I couldn't click it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use html as a global text in your view header area and insert the two links. There's no out of the box solution for your issue. There's a dev version of a module that you need, as specified here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83613/in-views-how-to-allow-users-to-toggle-between-a-grid-and-list

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this can easily be done using Views alone with a nice tabbed menu:

- Create your view page as normal, with the default information provided, except for the url - set that to whatever you want, in my example /tabs
- change the Display name under Page details to: Base (just to make things easier to read later on)
- Add a Page
- Change the Display name to the format type of the default page, presumably 'List View'
- set up the format, show, fields, filter, sort, etc. how you want the list view to be displayed - be sure to change the 'For' drop down from All displays to 'This page (override)' - or the changes you make will be set for all the pages, but you want different settings for each page
- set Path: tabs/list
- set Menu: Default menu tab, Title: View as List, Parent: already exists
- Add a Page
- Change the Display name to the format type of the second page, presumably 'Thumbnail View'
- set up the format, show, fields, filter, sort, etc. how you want the thumbnail view to be displayed - be sure to change the 'For' drop down from All displays to 'This page (override)' - or the changes you make will be set for all the pages, but you want different settings for each page
- set Path: tabs/thumbnail
- set Menu: menu tab, Title: View as Thumbnails, Menu: Navigation

  This should create a tabbed menu at the top of your view for easy navigation by users:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can remove title by setting it to `<none>` or leaving it empty. Then other block can be used to look like title with links on it.